# Javascript - Object.assign causes undefined error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, undefined

In my code as shown below, I am using `Object.assign(source, target)`, which is an ES6 construct.  This is failing with error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'Object.assign({}, inputObject)')

The code:

```js
function replace(inputObject) {
  const outputObject = Object.assign({}, inputObject);

  const lengths = Object.keys(outputObject).map((obj) => {
    return obj.length;
  });

  // ... Some more logic

  return outputObject;
}
  
replace({url: 'host:port/{gr.vars.id}/path'});
```

My question is:  The arrow functions are working perfectly fine, which are also an ES6 construct, but the `Object.assign` invokation is failing with the above error message.

I am calling the replace function as follows:

```
replace({url: 'host:port/{gr.vars.id}/path'});
```

**P.S.  The only intention of the Object.keys part is to demonstrate that arrow functions work.  So any errors there may be ignored safely.**

Comment: How are you calling the `replace` function?

Comment: Its not outputObject.keys, its Object.keys(outputObject)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I dont see any error in your snippet..Stack snippet is not throwing it

Comment: no error in the snippet

Comment: you forget to mention the environment you're running. also, are you using any polyfills for Object.assign()?

Comment: because it supports arrow functions, it doesn't mean that other ES6 features are available.

Comment: @AndréWerlang I am not using any polyfills.  But ES6 is supported so I should not need any polyfills, right?

Comment: it's the same on all browsers?

Comment: which browser are you using? check its version and compatiblity of es6 features like these. check this on latest chrome browser.if its working add polyfills to work on other browsers.or use babel